# Detect if there is a next, while in an each loop

Tags: jquery

I will try and let the code speak for itself here: what if condition can I use to check if there will be another iteration after the current one?

```
$('#%id% td').each(function(){ 
if(??????????){                       // if there will be a next iteration
while($(this).height() == thisheight){
    // do something here on this iteration, but only if there will be another.
}  
}
});
```

Comment: If this the entire content of the `each` loop, this can easily be solved with a selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems you want to process every element but the last one, you can simply remove the last element from the set, with [`.slice` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$('#%id% td').slice(0, -1).each(function() {
    // no need for `if` statement here
    // ...
});
```

The answer to your original question would be to compare the current iteration against the number of elements:

```
var $elements = $('#%id% td');
var max = $elements.length - 1;

$elements.each(function(index) { 
    if (index < max) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Persect..! I was to wrapped up with the .next() function, to think outside the .each() loop. Thank you.

Comment: @Felix Your update is by far the most elegant solution for my needs, thanks again.